# Return contents of url after posting login in Swift?

Tags: php, json, swift

So I've got a few lines that will "login" to the web page, and they fetch the contents and print them to the console, but I can't figure out how to get the results out of the "task" and use them later on in the code.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/mobilelogin.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let username = email_input.text;
    let password = password_input.text;
    var postString = "username="
    postString += username!
    postString += "&password="
    postString += password!
    print(postString);
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(request.HTTPBody);
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in guard error == nil && data != nil
        else {
            // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        print("responseString = \(responseString)");
        return

    }
    print("This is the task string")
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return from a closure, you need to use a "callback".

We make a function for your code:

```
func getData(username username: String, password: String)
```

but instead of adding a return type, we add a callback, here named "completion":

```
func getData(username username: String, password: String, completion: (response: String)->()) {

}
```

And inside the function, we use this callback at the location where the data will be available:

```
func getData(username username: String, password: String, completion: (response: String)->()) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/mobilelogin.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var postString = "username="
    postString += username
    postString += "&password="
    postString += password
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data where error == nil else {
            fatalError(error!.debugDescription)
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("response = \(response)")
            fatalError("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        }

        guard let str = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
            fatalError("impossible to get string from data")
        }

        completion(response: str)

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And you will use it like this:

```
getData(username: email_input.text!, password: password_input.text!) { (response) in
    print(response)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get it as a variable? For label setting?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). For your variable: of course! :) You do what you want. In `getData`, instead of `print(response)`, just use the response as you need it, for a label or anything else.